# ArrayTypeMismatchException thrown when adding MediaTypeHeaderValue to JsonFormatter.SupportedTypes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to add a supported type to the JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes collection and keep getting this error:

System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array

The only type that I can see the array taking is of MediaTypeHeaderValue. I cannot for the life of me figure out what is going on. HELP!

My code:

```
 Friend Sub Register(config As HttpConfiguration)

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(New MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"))

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my projects web.config was referencing version 4.0.0.0 of the system.net.http assembly

`<add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a/">`

I changed it back to the 2.0.0.0 assembly and the function worked as usual

`<add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a/">`